# synchronous reset D flip-flop with three inputs

Tags: flipflop

I can't find the schematic of D flip-flop with synchronous reset , that is , D flip-flop with three inputs, D,CLK and reset ; and two outputs ,Q1 and Q2

I only found the schematic with "two"  inputs,D and CLK;or  "four"  inputs, D,CLK,reset and set,from the Internet.

Can anyone help me??please.......

Comment: Take the 4 input one and ignore the set, that is, hold it false and remove any following logic that no longer changes state as a result.

Comment: so are the output of 4 input D flip-flop  and 2 input  D flip-flop  the same?

Comment: Make the reset synchronous with another d type.

Comment: commercial packaged flip-flops may have one or both outputs brought out, but the internal latch always has \$Q\$ and \$\overline{Q}\$ outputs. For instance, LS74 makes both outputs available, but LS174 only brings out the Q outputs to use fewer pins.

Comment: Synchronous means the set or reset only works when the clock occurs.  The set/reset input on the vast majority of parts are asynchronous and will set/reset the flip-flop no matter what the clock input is doing.

Comment: i still didn't understand,do you have an example?By the way,is it possible to do something to let asynchronous d flip flop become synchronous?for example,change NAND by AND